# Xamarin: How to pass information from a Prompt to viewmodel

Tags: xamarin

I'm a beginner in Xamarin and I'm trying to make a page where you can stock entries of your financial status by

1. clicking a toolbar button
2. prompt appears
3. it's added in the observable collection.
   But I can't seem to figure out a way to pass the info from the prompt to the viewmodel collection.

Here's the code:

xaml:

```xml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Jupiter.Pages.Function_Pages.FinancePage"
             x:Class="Jupiter.Pages.Function_Pages.Finance"
             BackgroundColor="MediumPurple">
  
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Add Entry" Clicked="{Binding AddFentryCommand}"></ToolbarItem>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout >
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding FinanceEntries}" BackgroundColor="MediumPurple">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextCell Text="{Binding Name}" Detail="{Binding Amount}"></TextCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            
        </StackLayout>
        
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

#C:

```c#
public partial class Finance : ContentPage
{
    ///Body

    public ListView LV;

    public Finance()
    {
        BindingContext = new FinanceViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
      
    }
    private async void goHome(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MenuPage());
    }
    public async void AddEntry(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's the name of the entry?");
        string result1 = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 2", "What's the amount?","Ok","Cancel",null,10,Keyboard.Numeric,"");
        int x = int.Parse(result1)

    }
    ///View Model
    class FinanceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        string _filename = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "finentries.txt");
        public int currententry = 0;
        public ObservableCollection<FinanceEntry> FinanceEntries { get; set; }
        public ICommand AddFentryCommand { get; set; }
        public FinanceViewModel()
        {
            AddFentryCommand = new Command(AddFentry);
        }
        public async void AddFentry()
        {
            currententry++;
            FinanceEntries.Add(new FinanceEntry { Name= $"entry {result}",Amount=x });
        }

#region INotifyPropertyChanged Implementation
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged == null)
                return;

            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first, keep a reference to your VM

```
public ListView LV;

private FinanceViewModel VM;

public Finance()
{
    BindingContext = VM = new FinanceViewModel();
    InitializeComponent();
  
}
```

then you can do this

```
public async void AddEntry(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string result = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 1", "What's the name of the entry?");
    string result1 = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 2", "What's the amount?");

    VM.FinanceEntries.Add(new FEntry(result,result1));
}
```

you need to initialize `FinanceEntries` otherwise it will be null and your app will crash

```
    public ObservableCollection<FinanceEntry> FinanceEntries { get; set; }
    public ICommand AddFentryCommand { get; set; }

    public FinanceViewModel()
    {
        AddFentryCommand = new Command(AddFentry);
        FinanceEntries = new ObservableCollection<FinanceEntry>();
    }
```

Comment: After doing this, it resolved the code issues but when i test it,the application crashes,  sending me to the .IOS main function and with the AppDelegate variable "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' ".Any idea on what could cause it or how to fix it? I would also add that i made some changes to your version to make it work :  string result1 = await DisplayPromptAsync("Question 2", "What's the amount?","Ok","Cancel",null,10,Keyboard.Numeric,"");
            VM.FinnanceEntries.Add(new FinnanceEntry { Name= result, Amount=x } ); (x being a parse)

Comment: are you initializing `FinanceEntries` in the constructor?

Comment: THX!Forgot about that, it fixed it